# Updating the UI Thread from within a loop: ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

All,

I have an Update Panel control that contains a label control.  I also have a Timer Control whose interval is set to 1 sec.  The timer control is suppose to set the text of the label control every second with the value of a public property that changes after each iteration of the loop.

However the resulting functionality is that after the entire loop completes then the UI is updated.  I'd like to know what would need to be done/coded to make sure the label control gets updated with the value of the _servername property after every iteration of the loop?

Heres my code:

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Timer ID="tmr" runat="server" Interval="1000" ontick="tmr_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
<div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udp1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tmr" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblInserts" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="udprg1" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="udp1"

        DisplayAfter="10">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <img src="media/ajaxloaderBlueLoading.gif" alt="ProgressImage" />
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <div id="_asyncCallsMadeDiv"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

//CODE BEHIND

```
   public string ServerName 
    {
        get { return _serverName; } 
        set { _serverName = value;} 
    }



   protected void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            lblInserts.Text = ServerName;
    }

   protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Loop through data
        while((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string [] arrayline = line.Split(','); 

            ServerStatus s = new ServerStatus
            {
                ServerName = arrayline[0],
                Purpose = arrayline[1],
                Primary = arrayline[2],
                Secondary = arrayline[3],
                OS = arrayline[4],
                MachineType = arrayline[5],
                Comments = arrayline[6],
                VMTools = arrayline[7],
                TimeSettings = arrayline[8],
                LastPatchDate = arrayline[9],
                CARemoval = arrayline[10],
                PLUpdate = arrayline[11],
                DefaultGatewayChange = arrayline[12]
            };

            _serverName = arrayline[0];
    }
```

Comment: Your aspx markup and code-behind seem almost unrelated to each other. As per your comment below, `tmrUdp1` should be `tmr` and call the `tmr_Tick` event handler. However, that event handler updates a label that doesn't exist in the aspx markup. I assume that should be `ltlCount` instead? Could you start by fixing either your aspx or code-behind?

Comment: @GuthMD and CheckRaise, apologies for the typos.  Also should readable now.

Comment: Can you explain the btnUpload_Click handler?  Where is `line` coming from? The operations there look pretty simple, and I would expect that whole loop is likely to complete in less than a second. You want it to postback to your page that often?

Comment: Just noticed that either the `while` or the `btnUpload_Click` is unclosed (missing one `}`). If there is some code missing, could you represent it with a comment, such as `// Time-consuming code here...` and place the missing `}`?

Comment: Another clarification: are you looking for the solution to be sequential? i.e., client submits to server, client waits on server processing, server waits for client to acknowledge update, repeat until complete? Or is it ok for the server to continue processing, with the client just getting an update to current state every second?

Answer (score 0):

The `onTick` property of your timer control is set to a method that doesn't exist.  You can rename tmr_Tick method in your code behind to tmrUdp1_Tick or set the `onTick` property to tmr_Tick

Comment: That is a typo this the updated timer control:
<asp:Timer ID="tmr" runat="server" Interval="1000" ontick="tmr_Tick" Enabled="true" />